# CSS3 / SVG Separator

Tags: css, svg, separator, divider

Im trying make header separator with svg or pure css3 like this:
[preview from design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUauE.png)

In header i have standart bootstrap 4 carousel

```html
<section class="slider">
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image:url(images/20180818_STP501.jpg);">
                    <div class="container position-relative h-100">
                        <div class="carousel-container">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2>Consectetuer adipiscing elit,<br/>diam nibh euismod tincidunt</h2>
                                <p>Enim ad veniam, ullamcorper<br/>suscipit aliquip commodo</p>
                                <div class="mt-5">
                                    <a href="#">Euismod</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image:url(images/20180818_STP501.jpg);">
                    <div class="container position-relative h-100">
                        <div class="carousel-container">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h2>Consectetuer adipiscing eli,<br/>diam nibh euismod tincidunt</h2>
                                <p>Enim ad veniam, ullamcorper<br/>suscipit aliquip commodo</p>
                                <div class="mt-5">
                                    <a href="#">Euismod</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Border radis working fine, but im need little rounded separator in bottom header. Its possible make with css3? Or need svg shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are asking: In the next example I'm using `clip-path` to clip the header. Please note that the path I'm using had a bounding box of 1/1 and `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.

> **MDN quote**: This value indicates that all coordinates inside the  element are relative to the bounding box of the element the clipping path is applied to. It means that the origin of the coordinate system is the top left corner of the object bounding box and the width and height of the object bounding box are considered to have a length of 1 unit value.

```css
#header {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/castell.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);  
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <path d="M0,0L0,.5 A.6,.6 0 0 0 1,.5L1,0z" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
 
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: Its work perfectly. But path have some white background. Possible resize svg path? My header have 80vh height, i make changes in path like M0,0L0,.6 A.5,.1 0 0 0 1,.5L1,0z for small curve. Now im need make white background some small [http://prntscr.com/nsci49](http://prntscr.com/nsci49)

Comment: I dont have paddings, this white space added svg element. Sorry maybe i dont undestand you, what is under-image?

Comment: Please check your code and remove the extra margin and padding. Can you link to a codepen or jsfiddle example?

Comment: Yes, here all my css and html [https://codepen.io/Elexer/pen/arqEZo](https://codepen.io/Elexer/pen/arqEZo)

Comment: It seams ok to me. What don't you like about it?

Comment: This is what i see [http://prntscr.com/nsdh3z](http://prntscr.com/nsdh3z)

Comment: Browser Chrome, latest

Comment: I'm sorry. It seams ok to me. Can you please explain what don't you like about it?

Comment: Oops. sorry, html in codepen not full, im updated with full code now. Use previous link for see, svg cut my slider. Withous svg its look like this [http://prntscr.com/nsdm6d](http://prntscr.com/nsdm6d)

Comment: If you mean the white space underneath please try this path: `<path d="M0,0L0,.8 A.8,.2 0 0 0 1,.8L1,0z" />`