# How to resize an SVG

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to resize an SVG that uses `clip-path`.  Despite my efforts and the docs I've read, this has yet to work.

The problem:
There are two icons. They are swapped on hover within an `::after` element. Currently the arrow SVG displays fine at 14px, but the link SVG is only partially displayed.  I have tried setting a height and width with the addition of `displayBox`, but no luck.

This is the CSS:

```
@mixin externalLink($color, $focusColor) {
  position: relative;
  color: $color;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  &::after {
    content: "";
    margin: $size-smaller;
    display: inline-block;
    background: $color;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    clip-path: url(#arrow-right);
    transition: color .25s;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: $focusColor;
    text-decoration: none;

    &::after {
      transform: scale(0.77, 0.77);
      background-color: $focusColor;
      clip-path: url(#link);
    }
  }
}

a {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   @include externalLink($yellow, $white);      
}
```

Here are the SVGs:

```
 <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="svg-def">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="arrow-right">
        <path d="M9.427.135a.527.527 0 0 0-.705 0 .428.428 0 0 0 0 .639l3.577 3.27H.494C.219 4.046 0 4.246 0 4.498c0 .251.219.458.494.458h11.805L8.722 8.22a.435.435 0 0 0 0 .645c.197.18.515.18.705 0l4.425-4.046a.418.418 0 0 0 0-.638L9.427.135z" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
  <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="svg-def">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="link">
        <path d="M16.506 8.003l-2.633 2.44a5.617 5.617 0 0 0-.383-2.676l1.376-1.3a2.44 2.44 0 0 0 .793-1.782c0-.65-.264-1.291-.793-1.78a2.816 2.816 0 0 0-1.922-.735c-.692 0-1.385.244-1.922.734L8.107 5.58c-.529.507-.802 1.157-.802 1.807 0 .65.264 1.291.802 1.781.236.22.355.498.355.768s-.119.54-.355.752c-.22.21-.52.312-.82.312-.292 0-.593-.101-.82-.312C5.492 9.768 5 8.568 5 7.37c0-1.199.492-2.398 1.467-3.31l2.897-2.676A5.234 5.234 0 0 1 12.926 0c1.293 0 2.587.464 3.58 1.384.993.92 1.494 2.12 1.494 3.318 0 1.19-.501 2.38-1.494 3.301zm-4.972 5.934l-2.913 2.697C7.638 17.544 6.345 18 5.043 18c-1.292 0-2.585-.455-3.568-1.366C.492 15.724 0 14.527 0 13.33c0-1.205.492-2.402 1.475-3.312l2.658-2.453a5.7 5.7 0 0 0 .382 2.697l-1.374 1.273a2.423 2.423 0 0 0-.792 1.778c0 .65.264 1.29.792 1.779.528.489 1.22.733 1.92.733.693 0 1.393-.244 1.921-.733l2.886-2.672c.547-.489.81-1.138.81-1.779 0-.649-.263-1.29-.81-1.778a1.042 1.042 0 0 1-.336-.776c0-.278.109-.556.336-.767.228-.21.528-.32.838-.32.3 0 .6.11.828.32.984.92 1.466 2.116 1.466 3.313a4.478 4.478 0 0 1-1.466 3.304z" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

This is the result in Chrome:

[image]

Any assistance you could provide would be a great help! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Part of the CSS is missing, could you please add it?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272762/css3-svg-separator/56273132#56273132

Comment: Sorry about the missing CSS - it is just a mixin.

Comment: and what about the HTML of this ? ( as SO recomandation https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )